# Download Images and mp3 with webview Android

Tags: java, android, webview, download, android-webview

I need to Download images(png,jpg,jpeg,gif) and mp3 in Android webView.
When i click download mp3 button or image button it not give any response.
Below is my code

```
@Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            if(webview.getUrl().contains(".mp3")){
                DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(
                        Uri.parse(url));
                request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "download mp3");

                DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                dm.enqueue(request);

            }
            if(url.indexOf("somesite.com") > -1 ) return false;

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }
```

Im using api levels from 21.

i also have storage read write permission in manifest.
Kindly Help